# How to set Laravel date to last month?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

Is there a way to "return time" in a Laravel project? And set the date to be last month and then all records added to have a timestamp from last month?

Comment: I think you can do it using Carbon Library. Using $date = Carbon::now()->subMonth(); fetch the last month and update in all records.

Comment: @HiteshPadhara Yes, this is the "manual" approach. But is there a way to do it globally? Like in the AppServiceProvider in the boot function or somewhere and affect the whole application?

Comment: What about changing date/time of the host OS where the Laravel app is installed?

Comment: @Don'tPanic There are other projects on the same VPS so this will affect them as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonth();

$model = new MyModel();
$model->created_at = $date;
$model->save();
```

Comment: I know how to do this for a single model. But is there a way to do it globally? Like in the AppServiceProvider in the boot function or somewhere?

Comment: Try using traits

Answer (score 0):

You can use Carbon, laravel has a helper built in

```
now()->subMonth();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-now)

You can view all available Carbon functions in your project at the following path:

`vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php`

Answer (score 0):

To get last month. [More Carbon options](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

1. `subMonth()` => if month back

   ```
   Carbon::now()->subMonth(); # (returns 2023-04-05) 
   # This will print the month back from the current date.
   ```
2. `startOfMonth` => If the start of the current month

   ```
   Carbon::now()->startOfMonth(); # (returns 2023-05-01) 
   # This will print the month's start date from the current date.
   ```
3. `subMonth()->startOfMonth()` => If start of the last month

   ```
   Carbon::now()->subMonth()->startOfMonth(); # (returns 2023-04-01) 
   # This will print the month's start date from the current date.
   ```

---

To Update your model, update your `$fillable`, and simple update/create will work

```
# Example if User update
$user->created_at = $lastMonth;
$user->updated_at = $lastMonth;
$user->save();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is one way to do it, but if there are a lot of models it will get a bit messy. Do you know if there is a way to do this globally and set the date for the application in the AppServiceProvider in the boot method and set the time and date there?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement you can do like that.

AppServiceProvider.php

```html
public function boot()
{
    
    Carbon::setTimezone('UTC');
    
    $lastMonth = Carbon::now()->subMonth();

    view()->share('lastMonth', $lastMonth);
}
```

You can direct access in view like the below code

```html
<p>Last month was: {{ $lastMonth->format('F Y') }}</p>
```